# How to calculate with metadata in footer

Tags: calculations, svn-multi

I have footer that draws on a svn version data field (package: svn-multi).  I would like to perform a simple calculation that subtracts a number from the reported version.

The footer code is
    `\lfoot{Ver: \textcolor{red}{1:}\textcolor{red}{\svnkw{LastChangedRevision}}}`

Currently `\svnkw{LastCHangedRevision}` is set at 286 so for this and future reports I need it to present 'LastCHangedRevision-285'

In response to MWE request:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Versioning
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnidlong {$HeadURL:  $}{$LastChangedDate: 2012-02-21 10:20:32 +0000 (Tue, 21 Feb 2012) $}{$LastChangedRevision: 287 $}{$LastChangedBy: $}
\svnid{$Id: BESA-2012.tex 287 2012-02-21 10:20:32Z $}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{color, lastpage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.0pt} \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.2pt}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{}
\cfoot{\svnkw{LastChangedDate}} \lfoot{Ver:
\textcolor{red}{1:}\textcolor{red}{\svnkw{LastChangedRevision}}}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\numexpr` command:

```
\lfoot{Ver: \textcolor{red}{1:%
  \number\numexpr\svnkw{LastChangedRevision}-285\relax}}
```