# How to increase the page number counter by a fixed number in latex

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change starting page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/change-starting-page-number)

Good day all!
I have two external pdf files I want to include as appendix in my report. The first file has 5 pages and the second has 7 pages. In order to make sure that my table of content reflect the appendices, I have include two appendices (Appendix A and B) in my latex file.

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{\label{app:appena}}
\section{Experiment 1}
\chapter{\label{app:appenb}}
\section{Experiment 2}
\end{appendices}
```

Now the last page of my work (without the appendices) is 32. Going by my method, Appendix A appears as page 33 and Appendix B appear as page 34 in table of content. How can I make the page number counter to increase by 5 so Appendix A appears as 33 and Appendix B appears as 38. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Yeah! You're right. Questions are very similar but What I need is something like 
\setcounter{page}{lastpage + 5}
So that my document is always complete even if the number of pages on my main document increases. I mean how do I specify the last page number in latex.

Comment: Answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45260/how-to-calculate-with-metadata-in-footer

Comment: `\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{5}`